# Как перевести вставки из WP плагина в HTML

Tags: wordpress, laravel, wordpress-плагины

Я переношу сайт с wp на Laravel. У меня есть дамп базы, в таблице posts хранятся посты, но проблема в том, что там прямо в тексте есть вставки из  wp плагина, я точно не знаю что это за плагин но вроде гугл сказал wp_breab.

```
 [caption id="attachment_2904" align="aligncenter" width="300"]
```

Так же в некоторых местах заметил вот такие вставки

```
[vc_row][vc_column][vc_column_text]
```

Первый вопрос - что это за плагин/ны?
Второй вопрос - как мне при наличии дампа базы перевести все эти вставки в HTML? Может есть способ через админку их раскрдить и так сохранить и сделать снова дамп?

Comment: Выведите через echo do_shortcode( $content ) и сохраните это все в БД как вам надо

Comment: Это визуал композер `vc_row`. Что за второй плагин - хз. Через админку вроде не получится так сделать. Только скриптом перебирать все посты, искать в них шорткоды и, как написали выше, пересохранять в базу результат, а не шорткод.

Comment: а в чем проблеме сделать екпорт контента, з приминением фильтра the_content, который конвертирует все шорткоды в html ? Не путайте с get_the_content (фильтры к нему не применяются, тоесть, шоркоды не конвертируются в html)/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> что это за плагин/ны?

Все вставки вида `[var]` называются [шорткоды](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode)

1. `[caption id="attachment_2904" align="aligncenter" width="300"]` - это [родной шорткод](https://codex.wordpress.org/Caption_Shortcode) для вывода подписи вложениям. В данном случае вложения с ID 2904.
2. `[vc_row][vc_column][vc_column_text]` - это шорткоды от плагина Visual Composer.

> Второй вопрос - как мне при наличии дампа базы перевести все эти вставки в HTML?

Правила SO: один топик - один вопрос.
Но если кратно, то никак. Точнее наверняка проще будет на Laravel написать обработчик таких шорткодов. Но с ID вложений уже может быть довольно сложно.
Или же выгружать контент не из базы, а из html-кода страниц. Но тут тоже может быть не всё однозначно (напр адаптив или зависимость от UA/referer и тп.).

Comment: Сори, не знал, я вроде как только начинаю и не особо знаю установленные правила) Но спасибо за совет и ответ, буду думать что с этим всем делать.

Comment: @ДимаСвободин я добавил ещё в ответ возможное решение.

Comment: @Vlad я нашел вот такой пакет, для ларки, пойду попробую) https://github.com/webwizo/laravel-shortcodes